# Davies-Meyer Hash Function

Tags: hash, one-way-function

So the Davies-Meyer Hash Function is: H<sub>i</sub> = H<sub>i−1</sub> ⊕ e<sub>xi</sub> (H<sub>i−1</sub>)

Say I pick H<sub>0</sub> = 1110 0011

And the message x<sub>1</sub> = "5" or "0000 0101"

Is this the correct way to compute H<sub>1</sub>?

H<sub>1</sub> = 1110 0011 ⊕ (0000 0101 ⊕ 1110 0011)

H<sub>1</sub> = 1110 0011 ⊕ (1110 0110)

H<sub>1</sub> = 0000 0101

I must be doing something wrong because the hash function always comes out the same as the message.

Answer (score 2):

The function $e$ takes two values: $x$ and $H$, and then merges them in a specific way. Your "way" is just XORing them. That's insecure, as you can see. Normally you use a block cipher for the function, like AES-128 for an input of 128 bit.

Example: $$ H_i = H_{i-1} \oplus AES_{xi}(H_{i-1}) $$

Comment: what happens if the message to evaluate has size equal to the key size? I make this question because in this case IV and $H_1$ are know, then the message is easy to get.